# Issue with joining

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT a.AuditoriumName,
     COUNT(d.StudentID) as Total_Visits 
                          from Auditorium a
     INNER JOIN AudiReservation c ON b.AudiID=c.AudiID
     INNER JOIN OrderHistory d on c.OrderID=d.OrderID
GROUP BY d.StudentID;
```

Tables

```
Auditorium - AudiID(pk), AudiName
AudiReservation - ReservationID(pk),AudiID(fk),OrderID(fk)
OrderHistory - OrderID(pk),StudentID(fk)
Student - StudentID(pk)
```

The problem here is, it does not uniquely identify the students. The main problem for that i believe is because AudiReservation has many to 1 relationship with OrderHistory. So, when the output comes, I get duplicate VenueNames and VenueIDs. I have tried grouping the OrderID of AudiReservation, to match only unique values with OrderHistory. But that does not seem to work. Could someone please help?

Input -

Student --

```
StudentID    Student_Name
1            Matt
2            Victor
```

Order History --

```
OrderID      StudentID
101            1
102            1
103            1
104            2
104            2
```

AudiReservation --

```
Reservation    OrderID    AudiID
001             101        AUDI01
002             102        AUDI01
003             103        AUDI01
003             104        AUDI02
004             101        AUDI02
005             102        AUDI02
```

Auditorium

```
AUDI01        Audi1-Tower of London
AUDI02        Audi2-London Bridge
```

Expected Output-

```
Auditorium  Name                Total Students Visit
AUDI01       Tower of London     2
AUDI02       London Bridge       2
```

Total Students Visit over here is the total number of unique students who visited the auditorium.

Comment: describe the table schemas one by one rather than a long description. Makes it more readable

Comment: Thanks. I guess you missed the student table. Also give a description of your requirement so that people here can try to find out what is wrong with your query

Comment: I'm sorry. You are still describing the problem with your query. You have to say what you need as output.

Comment: show your sample output

Comment: we see the expected output. Now where is the sample input

Comment: can you describe what `Total Students Visit` mean?

Comment: how many unique students visited the Auditoriums.

Comment: # of unique student visits for `AUDI01` is `1` and not `2`. See my sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to `group` using Audi_id and take count of `distinct` students

```
SELECT a.AuditoriumName,
     COUNT( distinct d.StudentID) as Total_Visits 
                          from Auditorium a
     INNER JOIN AudiReservation c ON a.AudiID=c.AudiID
     INNER JOIN OrderHistory d on c.OrderID=d.OrderID
GROUP BY a.AudiID;
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, when the output comes, I get duplicate VenueNames and VenueIDs

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT the_unique_id_field_your_need)`. Like this `COUNT(DISTINCT VenueID)`. I don't know which table has the column to choose proper alias.

Comment: Then post your table structures (with all fields), desired output etc. You can create sqlfiddle for the structures and add some sample data to execute queries.

Answer (score 0):

**see the execution in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2036/1)**

```
select D.AudiID,E.AuditoriumName,D.Total_Visits
from Auditorium E,
(
    select C.AudiID,count(distinct C.StudentId) as Total_Visits
    from 
    (
        select A.AudiID,B.StudentID
        from AudiReservation A, OrderHistory B
        where A.orderID = B.orderID
    )C
    group by C.AudiID
)D
where E.AudiID = D.AudiID
```

Comment: Get an error - unknown table 'C' in the field list.